# Use logstash to copy index on same cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an `ES 1.7.1` cluster and I wanted to "reindex" an Index. Since I cannot use `_reindex` I came across this tutorial to use logstash to copy an index onto a different cluster. However in my case I want to copy it over to the same cluster. This is my logstash.conf :

```
input {
  # We read from the "old" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "myhost"
    port => "9200"
    index => "my_index"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

output {
  # We write to the "new" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    host => "myhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "logstash_test"
    index_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # We print dots to see it in action
  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp", "@version" ]
  }
}
```

This errors out with the following error message:

```
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>[{:scheme=>"http", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :host=>"myhost", :path=>"", :port=>"80", :protocol=>"http"}], index=>"my_index", scroll=>"5m", query=>"{\"query\": { \"match_all\": {} } }", docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"]>
  Error: Connection refused - Connection refused {:level=>:error}
Failed to install template: http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known {:level=>:error}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: which version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: @Val As per the tutorial I used version `1.5.0`. Even tried the latest one (`6.2.3`)

Comment: Logstash seems to not be able to reach ES. Are you sure about the `myhost` setting? What do you have for `network.host` in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file?